# Flutter: Is it possible to enclose several expansion tiles inside a container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Because I want to put a title header and the individual expansion tiles when opened will change the size of the container with shadow depending on the text contents. Not sure if there is a better widget or package that can achieve this.

[image]

Comment: You can use `ExpansionTile` Wiget

Comment: hello @nagendra nag, I did use expansion tiles for the questions. It the rounder corner box and headline text that I am having trouble adding. hope this clears the question further :)

Comment: customize  `ExpansionTile` according to your requirements

Comment: Can you include your widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ExpansionTile` widget.

code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.2),
                blurRadius: 20.0, // soften the shadow
                spreadRadius: 0.0, //extend the shadow
                offset: const Offset(
                  2.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
                  2.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Radio(value: true, groupValue: null, onChanged: null),
                    Text('FAQs'),
                  ],
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  itemCount: _question.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                        title: Text(
                          _question[i].que,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            children: _buildExpandableContent(_question[i]),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

method which gives the answer:

```
_buildExpandableContent(Question question) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];
    columnContent.add(
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          question.ans,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return columnContent;
  }
```

List of the question:

```
final List<Question> _question = [
    Question(
      que: 'Question 1',
      ans:
          'Answer 1',
    ),
    Question(
      que: 'Question 2',
      ans:
          'Answer 2',
    ),
  ];
```

model:

```
class Question {
  final String que;
  final String ans;

  Question({required this.que, required this.ans});
}
```

Output:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQzJn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  body: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
    child: ListView(
      children: const [
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.radio_button_off),
          title: Text("Frequently Asked Questions"),
        ),
        Divider(),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("What"),
          children: [Text("?")],
        ),
        Divider(),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("What"),
          children: [Text("?")],
        ),
        Divider(),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("WHo"),
          children: [Text("?")],
        ),
        Divider(),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("How"),
          children: [Text("?")],
        ),
        Divider(),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("How"),
          children: [Text("?")],
        ),
        Divider(),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("Are"),
          children: [Text("?")],
        ),
        Divider(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Output: [image]

Comment: hello @MendelG and Saiful, I need to enclose all the expansion tiles inside one box/container with rounded corners, as shown in the reference photo. :)